# ReportPortal "Notification" From field is grayed out

Tags: reportportal

In report-portal (v4.2) the notifications From field is grayed out with a default value of "reportportal@example.com" set. I can't seem to find where to change it.

Screenshot: ReportPortal-Notification-Settings

[image]

is it a bug or me misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem I faced, so I added email notification details using report portal api. Please find the below screenshot for your reference.

[Report Portal API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO1vT.png)

Answer (score 0):

As for today, it is only possible to update `From` field in **'Email notification'** component via API call.

Please send

`PUT http://host:8080/api/v1/project/{project_name}/emailconfig`

RQ body should have next required parameters:

```
`{
  "emailCases": [
    {
      "recipients": [
        "<email_address_of_recipient>"
      ],
      "sendCase": "ALWAYS"
    }
  ],
  "emailEnabled": true,
  "fromAddress": "<email_address_from_Email_server_settings>"
}`
```

In RP v5 the field will be removed from UI. 
Sender address will be inherited from Email server settings configuration (Administrative part).

https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/issues/516